# Recording frames generated by Open GL ES on android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am capturing frames from camera and rendering them in real time via OpenGL ES 2.0. Now I want to record them to a movie file along with audio. On iPhone, I had AVAssetWriter that would take care of the recording, giving me 30fps. What are my options on android? I tried search but couldn't find any.

UPDATE: For those wondering what I am trying to do, see this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidillusion.videocamillusion&hl=en

This is the only app i found that could perform 30FPS video rendering/recording. My goal is to try to figure out how it is done.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this yourself. And since you're using the camera, you obviously can't use the simulator. 1. Find a device with HDMI output, and get all the necessary equipment to record from it 2. Get a compatible, rooted device, and use the Screencast app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast 3. Find something similar to #2

Comment: That's the problem. Recording is part of the functionality of the app. I don't want to record just to 'show off' features/trailer. The app is a green-screen application thats allows user to record video with a custom background.

Comment: Ah, my bad. So what you're actually wanting to do is record the contents of whatever you render to OpenGL, and save it as a video on device...

In that case, you still need to jump through hurdles to get it working.

You should use glReadPixels to grab everything from the screen (you should be able to do this at a fast enough rate), then you'll have to get deep into some video encoding stuff... http://ffmpeg.org/ is probably your best bet, but I don't know how NDK-friendly that is. Best of luck!

Comment: Well, if MediaRecorder accepted programatic sources I would say to use that. But maybe you need to build and use ffmpeg?

Comment: For the sake of optimisation, you should render to a texture that is half width, half height of the screen, render it onto a quad on the screen, then save bitmaps with glReadPixels. Althought I don't think you can achieve 30 FPS with this method you could give it a try, but I don't think it's feasable the way you're doing it. Can you provide further info about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you need to readback any data from OpenGL?

Comment: In case of ``com.androidillusion.videocamillusion`` app rendering into a FBO in YUV-color with later ``glReadPixels()`` will do. After that just use the FFmped/libtheora to compress the video. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you capture frames from camera and render them with OpenGL i assume that you already have those frames in your memory and you don't need to use OpenGL to read-back the rendered images.

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MingwCompilationGuide)  or [libtheora](http://www.theora.org/downloads) libraries to interleave your audio/video streams into a file. Both can be compiled for Android and are NDK-friendly.

There are a lot of tutorials for both libraries.

In case of Theora, you can convert you frames to YUV-color using GLES 2 shaders.

**P.S.** If you need to read something back from OpenGL ES - just use `glReadPixels()` and proceed with these video encoding libraries.

Comment: But glReadPixels is too slow for realtime video encoding, is there any faster way?

Comment: It should work fine until the resolution is not too high. Full resolution on retina display will not work. We have good experience with 800x480.

Comment: @SergeyK. have you successfully used FFmpeg and libtheora into an Android application running on many different processors? I have spent a good deal of time investigating this and it seems as though most apps that attempt to use ffmpeg have different builds for different processors. For a mass market application (especially one that wants to remain under 15-20MB), this hasn't seemed a reasonable solution.

Comment: libtheora - positive. But i didn't try FFmpeg.

Comment: glReadPixels is very slow, how can i get gl context faster? Or can i draw the gl context to a frame buffer inside the rendering?

Comment: I want to compress the video using libtheora because ffmpeg takes too much time to compress the video.